# ejabberd server login failed from android device

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I installed and initialized **ejabberd** **XMPP** server 18.09 for Windows. I've taken android chat application from Github, run it on android studio 3.2.1.
**ejabberd** **server** login successfully from the desktop (using http://localhost:5280/admin/) but when I try to login application from an Android device with `jabber id`, it gives "No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s) error.

Please help me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to login, does ejabberd show in the log the connection attempt, like this?

```
10:06:00.806 [info] (<0.509.0>) Accepted connection ::ffff:127.0.0.1:43779
 -> ::ffff:127.0.0.1:5222
```

When you login in the WebAdmin, you provide a JabberID like adminuser@example.com right? Then, in the jabber client, try setting as JabberID that same adminuser@example.com

Comment: Yes, I am using the same JabberID in jabber client also. I get this error: W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: host-unknown You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
    <stream:error><host-unknown xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>

Comment: I resolved the "host-unknown" error but now I am getting timeout error i.e   Exception while waiting for closing stream element from the server XMPPTCPConnection[not-authenticated] (2)
    org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s)